# Is there any way to restrict the releases download only to registered users?

Tags: github

Is there any way to restrict the release download only to registered users, for a public repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  Access to the releases and release assets are allowed to exactly those people that have access to the repository.  For a public repository, that's everyone.

If you want to restrict the set of users who can download release assets, you'll need to either restrict access to the repository or use a different solution.  For example, if you want to restrict binaries to paid users, you'll need to build something yourself.